Has FIFA really recognized intercontinental cup winners as world champions?
According to English Wikipedia, and several spanish speaking online websites, FIFA has recognized intercontinental cup winners (from the original intercontinental cup of 1960-2000) as world champions. This appears a lot of in spanish speaking countries, since it was a petition of CONMEBOL (the continental governing body of football in South America) where most countries speak Spanish.

Since 2017, past Intercontinental Cup winners have been recognised by
FIFA as club world champions.

Intercontinental Cup - English Wikipedia
Notice this claim has no reference to support it in Wikipedia.
Also, and however, this is one of the odd claims that you can't find evidence anywhere in the official website (or at least, I can't) . It's true that the official twitter account of CONMEBOL once asked to turn official the intercontinental cup winners as world champions to FIFA, the tweet still can be seen, but the reply of FIFA can't be seen anywhere.
Also, in the year 2000, both the intercontinental cup organized by CONMEBOL-UEFA, and the FIFA Club World Cup organized by FIFA were played. Who was supposed to be the world champion in 2000 then? Were there 2 world champions in one year? It doesnt make sense.
So my question is, has FIFA really recognized intercontinental cup winners as world champions?

Have you read the rest of the article, specifically the section entitled "FIFA recognition"?

@F1Krazy An article appeared in a spanish website, it cites FIFA as official source, it says FIFA just said it only recognizes club world cup champions as world champions. The article is posted in the largest sports newspaper of Argentina with over 6.7 million followers https://www.facebook.com/diarioole/posts/pfbid0VQyZSNDqoJnQ54PqH6PSsz6DAMR7eXcxh4iNPxgf7oHzHhfBUiEAj2wwpfKfyFGql

The linked article shows the Intercontinental Cup winners prior to 2000 being recognised as world champions, but not the ones from 2000 to 2004. Which does contradict their earlier statement, but doesn't mean they don't recognise the Intercontinental Cup winners at all, as you seem to be implying. In any case, the point of my original comment is that you say "this claim has no reference to support it in Wikipedia", but there are well over a dozen references if you can actually be bothered to read the whole article.

@F1Krazy you are right, it says it doesnt recognize the intercontinental cup as world trophy only for some years

@Pablo There is a follow up to that Facebook post, posted a few hours later: https://www.facebook.com/share/p/YAdkthRDWLEGUrKg/?mibextid=WC7FNe It was not a change in FIFA policy. It was just an error on a list that has been corrected.

Yes, FIFA officially recognizes all clubs winning the Intercontinental Cup as “world champions.” This was decided by the FIFA Council on October 27, 2017, and announced by FIFA on their Inside FIFA website:

The meeting in Kolkata covered a wide array of topics and saw the FIFA Council passing a number of important decisions, including the following:


· Recognition of all European and South American teams that won the Intercontinental Cup – played between 1960 and 2004 – as club world champions.

Yes, this means that there are two world champion clubs for the year 2000 (Boca Juniors having won the Intercontinental Cup and Corinthians with the FIFA Club World Cup).

This post needs to be updated. FIFA just removed the recognition of intercontinental cup as world champion for the years 2000-2004 . Update it, and I will accept the answer again

@Pablo FIFA has not removed the recognition of these champions. It was just an error on a list of champions that has since been corrected.
